# Struts2: Getting error with struts.xml

Tags: eclipse, struts2, web-frameworks

I am using Struts2 When i am writting a program, in `struts.xml` file getting warning "the file cannot be validated as there was a connection problem " at the line:-" !DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd" "

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">; 
<struts> 
  <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" /> 
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> 
  <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default"> 
  <action name="testAction" class="javaguys.tutorials.actions.TestAction"> 
     <result name="success">/Home.jsp</result> 
  </action> 
  </package> 
</struts>
```

Comment: can you post your struts config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ';' from the end of your DOCTYPE
this should be at the root of your struts config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
```

Comment: thanks bro,i have just one error:   <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />